# Navbar to get horizontal layout

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, reactstrap

I have the following code for a navbar in a React app. The navbar content looks fine when the browser window is wide, but once I drop past the `navbar-expand-lg` cutoff, the icons align vertically one above the other. How do I prevent that? (see screenshot below code)

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
  Badge,
  Nav,
  Navbar,
  NavbarBrand,
  NavbarToggler,
  NavItem,
  NavLink,
} from 'reactstrap';
import FontAwesome from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';

class Header extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Navbar dark color="dark" expand="lg" className="w-100 p-1">
        <NavbarToggler className="d-flex"/>
        <NavbarBrand className="ml-3" href="/">Logo</NavbarBrand>
        <Nav className="d-flex ml-auto" horizontal="end" navbar>
          <NavItem>
            <NavLink href="#">
              <FontAwesome icon={["fas","bell"]} className="text-light" size="lg" />
              <Badge pill color="danger">5</Badge>
            </NavLink>
          </NavItem>
          <NavItem>
            <NavLink href="#">
              <FontAwesome icon={["fas","clipboard"]} className="text-light" size="lg" />
              <Badge pill color="warning">5</Badge>
            </NavLink>
          </NavItem>
          <NavItem>
            <NavLink href="#">
              <i className="icon-location-pin"></i>
              <Badge pill color="info">5</Badge>
            </NavLink>
          </NavItem>
        </Nav>
        <NavbarToggler className="d-flex ml-3"/>
      </Navbar>
    );
  }
}

export default Header;
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you still want to use the mobile collapse menu?

Comment: @ZimSystem: No, The hamburger icons will be used to trigger left and right sidebars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve what you want, you need to use the `flex-row` class to turn what normally would be a flex column into a flex row.

Here is the complete working code for your navbar including both hamburger menus (I have hidden the right menu items on `lg` screens with the `d-lg-none` class):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <button class="navbar-toggler mr-3" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>

    <div class="ml-auto order-lg-last">
        <ul class="navbar-nav flex-row">
            <li class="nav-item pr-3 pr-lg-0">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                    <i class="fa fa-bell" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <span class="badge badge-pill badge-danger">5</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item pr-3 pr-lg-0">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                    <i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <span class="badge badge-pill badge-warning">6</span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                    <i class="fa fa-telegram" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary">8</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <button class="navbar-toggler ml-3" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent2" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent2" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation2">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Left Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Left Link 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Left Link 2</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent2">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto d-lg-none">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Right Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Right Link 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Right Link 2</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

The padding on the right for the icons is adjusted the padding-right classes `pr-3 pr-lg-0` i.e. zero or default padding on `lg` screens and up and 3 units right padding on smaller screens.

Also note how the `order-lg-last` class switches things around on `lg` screens and above.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace `navbar-expand-lg` with `navbar-expand`

Comment: When I remove the `expand="lg"` attribute, I get the second form only with the icons in a vertical stack. I need them to lie horizontally.